# Parse search queries in sql 2005 FTS

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, query-parser

In lucene, we can use **QueryParser.Parse(query)** to find out how the given query is interpreted by lucene. Its very helpful. I am looking for some kind of API or build in sys functions to identify how the **FTS** parses given search string.

I found **sys.dm_fts_parser** procedure in sql 2008 does the same job, but currently am working on ms sql 2005. so its not useful.

And using **Language Resource Test (Lrtest.exe)** in sharepoint to analyze the query string. But am out of luck here too.

so can anyone suggest a mechanism to find out how **FTS** interprets the given query??